# How to constrain view's width to device width in interface builder?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I have this view hierarchy

[image]

I want my content to grow vertically in content view but not horizontally. so I want to constrain ContentView's width to be the same as device's width. How can I do this in **Interface Builder**?

**Note:** The image's width in Image View is bigger than device's width, so right now ContentView's size grows both vertically and horizontally

Comment: Add leading and trailing constraint to superview of ContentView's. you should also give imageview's width as the contect'view width.

Answer (score 0):

just add the constraints to content view as leading space,trailing space,top space,bottom Space along with fix content view width constraint as constant and then create the outlet for width constraint value and in view controller side write method as

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubViews
{

_scrollViewContentViewWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width;

}